# Python: How to get rid of circular dependency involving decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, circular-dependency

I had got a following case of circular import (here severly simplified):

`array2image.py` conversion module:

```
import tuti

@tuti.log_exec_time # can't do that, evaluated at definition time
def convert(arr):
    '''Convert array to image.'''
    return image.fromarray(arr)
```

`tuti.py` test utils module:

```
import array2image

def log_exec_time(f):
    '''A small decorator not using array2image'''

def debug_image(arr):
    image = array2image.convert(arr)
    image = write('somewhere')
```

It failed with NameError. This didn't look right to me, as there was really no circular dependency there. I was looking for a *neat* way to avoid that or an explanation... and half way through writing this question I found it.

Moving the `import` below the decorator in `tuti.py` resolves NameError:

```
def log_exec_time(f):
    '''A small decorator not using array2image'''

import array2image

def debug_image(arr):
    image = array2image.convert(arr)
    image = write('somewhere')
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer you came up with is a valid solution.

However, if you were that worried about circular dependencies, I would say that log_exec_time would belong in its own file since its not dependent on anything else in tuti.py.

Comment: The best solution is to move the decorator to another module and avoid circular dependency.

Comment: Yep, it's MUCH better to entirely avoid the circular dependency, than to try to skirt it with fragile solutions such as this one.

Comment: This was an obvious workaround and a reason, why I at all asked. I'm more happy with my solution, as this would be creating a module to hold 4-lines-of-code function and that's so Java :)... and it wouldn't fit the color of my license... Nah... Ausschwitz!